# can't convert symbol into integer error when saving user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

So here is my issue. I have been working with users I created at the beginning of my project for a month now. Today I switched from sqllite to sqlserver to meet client requirements and when I went to use my registration form to create a new user I got the following error:

```
can't convert Symbol into Integer

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"51nF50CYGNqz3N4o7TUYSyWeTadulXojQBPqERjvlcY=",
 "user"=>{
   "email"=>"test@blizzardlabs.com",
   "login"=>"bgarrison",
   "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
   "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
   "profile_attributes"=>{
     "prefix"=>"",
     "first_name"=>"Bill",
     "last_name"=>"Garrison",
     "suffix"=>"",
     "birthday"=>"1983-06-01",
     "phone_numbers_attributes"=>{
       "0"=>{
         "info"=>"1234567890",
         "label"=>"Cell"
       }
     }
   }
 },
 "commit"=>"Register"}
```

I have a feeling that at some point I messed up the registration process but I can't for the life of me figure out where. User-> has_one profile-> has_many phone_numbers.

User Controller:

```
def create    
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save
      @profile = @user.profile
      flash[:notice] = "Your account has been created."
      redirect_to(@user)
    else
      flash[:notice] = "There was a problem creating you."
      render :action => :new, :layout => 'logged_out'
    end
  end
```

User Model:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Accessible attributes
  attr_accessible :login,
    :email,
    :password,
    :password_confirmation,
    :profile_attributes,
    :active

  # Associations
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true

  # Allows for a profile hash in user creation (stored in :profile_attributes)
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

Profile Model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Accessible Attributes
  attr_accessible :birthday, 
    :company_id, 
    :first_name, 
    :last_name, 
    :prefix, 
    :suffix, 
    :phone_numbers_attributes,
    :addresses_attributes

  # Model Associations
  has_many :phone_numbers, :as => :contactable, :class_name => "PhoneNumber", autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_numbers, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blan
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Update:1      Also, I have tested some and realized if I leave out the phone number then it works.....if I then update using the same form and add a phone number everything works fine.

Comment: can you include the code where the error happens?

Comment: I did....its the first line of the create method: @user = User.new(params[:user])

Comment: Oh I also forgot to mention that I have: accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_numbers, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

Comment: sorry. not sure what's causing the issue. upvoting

Comment: Man, this is becoming even more troublesome. I made NO changes and now the error has randomly changed to "unknown attribute: password"...same params sent through....same controllers and models....weird EDIT: That is not true....I have in fact installed the debugger...maybe its giving me something more specific?

Comment: maybe that's better. i'm assuming you don't have a password column and just forgot to add an attr_accessor for it?

Comment: I am using authlogic, so when using "acts_as_authentic" in the user model it takes care of that. I have password as an accessible attribute but by definition it doesnt get included into the database

Comment: ah ok. didn't know you were using authlogic. still baffled then.

Comment: FYI, I added attr_accessor: password to the model and it got rid of the password error and im back to can't convert Symbol into Integer error. Im thinking that maybe when installing debugger it updated authlogic or something that caused this to be enforced. Either way ....back to square one at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a couple days of banging my head against the wall I have finally figured this out. However to understand it I need to explain my model's a bit better.

Basically, from above you can see that a User has a profile which has many phone_numbers and addresses through a polymorphic association (:as => :contactable ). However, contactable is actually a base class called ContactInformation which uses STI to contain contactable information of all types.

At one point I decided that having 4 extra fields for addresses was cluttering up the STI relationship but I still wanted to keep it. My solution was to serialize all those fields into the "info" field of ContactInformation. Right now, phone numbers only have "number" as a field that is serialized and stored into "info" but if I ever want to seperate it out into "area code" "extension" etc the implementation will be simple.

This leads to the problem. On my registration form I was using label / info for my phone_number fields instead of label / number. I had edited my edit form but not my new form (yes i know they should be the same one but I have a special ajax form for editing).

Here is the code for ContactInformation / PhoneNumber / Address

```
class ContactInformation < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :contactable_id, :contactable_type, :info, :label, :type
  belongs_to :contactable, :polymorphic => true

end

class PhoneNumber < ContactInformation
  attr_accessible :number
  stash :number, in: :info

  #----------------------------------Validations--Start-------------------------
  validates :number, presence: true
  #----------------------------------Validations--End---------------------------
end

class Address < ContactInformation
  attr_accessible :street_address, :city, :state, :postal
  stash :street_address, :city, :state, :postal, in: :info

  #----------------------------------Validations--Start-------------------------
  validates :street_address, :city, :state, :postal, presence: true
  #----------------------------------Validations--End---------------------------
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested attributes should be passed in as Array:

```
"user"=>{
  "email"=>"test@blizzardlabs.com",
  "login"=>"bgarrison",
  "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
  "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
  "profile_attributes"=>[
    {
      "prefix"=>"",
      "first_name"=>"Bill",
      "last_name"=>"Garrison",
      "suffix"=>"",
      "birthday"=>"1983-06-01",
      "phone_numbers_attributes"=>{
        "0"=>{
          "info"=>"1234567890",
          "label"=>"Cell"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```